# Can't boot my PC and cant find bootable partition in table

Tags: linux, windows, boot

So I was trying to get Linux Ubuntu on my old PC (it had w7 before). While linux was formatting my HDD my PC displayed an error and crashed. Now I can't boot anything even if I put in a bootable USB or CD. I changed the boot order and I also tryed different ISO's.
I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer crashed during a formatting, especially while shrinking your Windows Partition, The partition itself is more then likely damaged beyond repair. (Well, feasible repair, you could still use a few tools to pull the files)

I would check that the partitions exist and that a Live Linux system can detect the partitions as what they should be. (NTFS for Windows, more than likely) If your partition doesn't exist you will have to start the process of recovering it...

At this point, if the partitions don't exist, or seems quite mutilated, it might be easier wiping the partition table from the drive and starting fresh. However if this is not an option, you will have to start finding ways to recover based on your problem.

However another problem is that a piece of Hardware (specificity RAM or the hard drive) has failed, and it is writing bad data to the disk. You might what to check those if you continue having this problem.

If you are looking for recovery advice, you might need to be more specific or start a new question.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for the responce. I was wondering how I could check if my RAm or HDD failed.

Comment: Just find a memory test ISO. I know one comes built into the Ubuntu ISO.